# Is there any way to put ubuntu on a HP touchpad?

Tags: hp, tablet, hp-touchpad

Is there any talk on getting on the touchpad? is it even possible?

Comment: What extra information are you looking for beyond the published advice on the webos forums? (http://liliputing.com/2011/08/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-an-hp-touchpad.html) & http://forums.webosnation.com/webos-development/289421-ubuntu-touchpad.html