# Can we install 12.10 on HP Touchpad? If so please give details

Tags: 12.10, tablet, hp-touchpad

I'm an Ubuntu enthusiast.I own a HP touchPad tablet running webOS. I love to run ubuntu 12.X on it. I've gone through few sites and videos, nothing is clear. Please help me in this.

Thanks
Tej

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139144/is-there-any-way-to-put-ubuntu-on-a-hp-touchpad